# Is there a way of increasing MAX_INTEGER in web3.js

Tags: transactions, raw

I am send a raw transaction using a wallet and sign it with private key but when I input the value it brings out error: value cannot exceed MAX_INTERGER(2^256-1)

const code = web3.utils.utf8ToHex('C:\file\data.json');

From: address
To: receiver
Value: web3.utils.toWei(code,'ether')